# Lightning Components: Is it possible that a component fires an Application Event and handle it by itself?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, event

Can Components subscribe and handle app-events which have been fired by themselves?

```
<aura:handler name="refresh" event="c:elfLC_recordRefresh" action="{!c.appEvent}"/>
<aura:registerEvent name="eventRecordRefresh" type="c:elfLC_recordRefresh"/>
```

It looks like I can fire the event successfully like this with no issues:

```
var appEvent = $A.get("e.c:elfLC_recordRefresh");
appEvent.setParams({"message" : "test"});
appEvent.fire();
```

But I' not able to receive and handle it like this:

```
appEvent : function(cmp, evt, hlp) {
    console.log('this should be logged...');
},
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I think yes, they can do it. Can you check by removing the name attribute from handler. I believe that is not required.

Comment: @manjit_singh cool thx, omitting the name solved the issue.

Comment: @manjit_singh You may want to put that as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think yes, they can do it. You will have to remove the name attribute from handler. I believe that is not required.